# GCM: Registering with Multiple Senders using InstanceId

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Previously registering with multiple senderId's was quite described and easy approach.

```
       final GoogleCloudMessaging instance = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
       final String registrationId = instance.register(senderId1, senderId2);
```

I could not find how to acheive the same using the InstanceId flow. I tried

```
              String token = instanceID.getToken("SENDER_ID1,SENDER_ID2,SENDER_ID3", GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

but seems like it does not work. I know that, registering getToken() for each senderId(authorizedEntity) would work, thus providing me 3 different token but the objective is to have 1 and only 1 registrationId.

Also if we go by [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) and use google services plugin in AS, there seems to be a
'**google-services.json**' file that consist only one google-project/client information.

Does it have any relation with that.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the internet for the solution in your problem, I found here in [Multiple GCM senders in the same app](https://github.com/layerhq/documentation/blob/master/android/guides/push-integration.md), that Google support multiple GCM senders in a single app, but you have to account for it. If not, one or more GCM senders will fail to send GCM intents, and GCM intents that do come in may randomly fail to reach GCM receivers in your manifest.

The best way to do this is to handle GCM registration yourself, rather than letting individual libraries perform the registration. Note that you would use gcm_defaultSenderId or googleCloudMessagingSenderId on the Layer client; instead, you'll have to join the sender IDs of each library with a comma.

This is a sample code on how to register multiple senderID using instanceID.

```
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        // Comma-concatenated sender IDs
        String senderIDs = "SENDER_ID_1,SENDER_ID_2";
        String token = instanceID.getToken(senderIDs, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        // ...
    }
}
```

To make this possible, all you need to do is have each sender generate its own project number. Then include those IDs in the sender field, separated by commas, when requesting a registration. Finally, share the registration ID with your partners, and they'll be able to send messages to your application using their own authentication keys.

For more information about instanceID, you can check this [page](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/#key_features).